# Drawer Navigator not activating in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

I put a button (hamburger menu) on the header, and when it gets clicked, the drawer or hamburger menu should open up. But it is not happening.
Please note I created a function Root for Drawer Navigation and
try to activate it through CategoryNavigator=><Stack.Navigator>. I guess the onPress of menu button is not doing what I am hoping for.

I want to keep this structure because I want the header title to change according to the screen but have the constant hamburger menu also visible on all screens.

Also, see the image.
[image: Screen showing hamberger menu]

Please see the code:

```js
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import React from 'react';
import CategoriesScreen from '../screens/CategoriesScreen';
import CategoryMealsScreen from '../screens/CategoryMealsScreen';
import MealDetailScreen from '../screens/MealDetailScreen';
import Colors from '../constants/Colors';

import FavoriteNavigator from './FavoriteNavigator';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { HeaderButtons, Item } from 'react-navigation-header-buttons';
import CustomHeaderButton from '../components/CustomHeaderButton';
import FavoriteScreen from '../screens/FavoriteScreen';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function Root() {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Favorites" component={FavoriteNavigator} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}

const CategoryNavigator = (props) => {
  const { navigation } = props;
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: Platform.OS === 'android' ? Colors.primaryColor : '',
        },
        headerTintColor:
          Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'white' : Colors.primaryColor,
        headerLeft: () => (
          <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={CustomHeaderButton}>
            <Item title="Menu" iconName="ios-menu" onPress={Root} />
          </HeaderButtons>
        ),
        headerBackVisible: true,
        headerBackTitle: '',
      }}
    >
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Categories"
        component={CategoriesScreen}
        options={{
          title: 'Categories',
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="CategoryMeals"
        component={CategoryMealsScreen}
        options={{
          title: 'Categroy Meals',
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="MealDetail"
        component={MealDetailScreen}
        options={{ title: ' ' }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

export default CategoryNavigator;
```

Also adding App.JS Code

````
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

import { enableScreens } from 'react-native-screens';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

import FavoriteScreen from './screens/FavoriteScreen';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import CategoryNavigator from './components/CategoryNavigator';
import Colors from './constants/Colors';
import FavoriteNavigator from './components/FavoriteNavigator';

enableScreens(true);

const fetchFonts = () => {
  return Font.loadAsync({
    'open-sans': require('./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf'),
    'open-sans-bold': require('./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf'),
  });
};

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function App() {
  const [fontLoaded, setFontLoaded] = useState(false);

  const primaryColor = Colors.primaryColor;
  const size = 25;

  if (!fontLoaded) {
    return (
      <AppLoading
        startAsync={fetchFonts}
        onFinish={() => setFontLoaded(true)}
        onError={(err) => console.log(err)}
      />
    );
  }

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator
        screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused, primaryColor, size }) => {
            let iconName;

            if (route.name === 'All') {
              iconName = focused ? 'ios-restaurant' : 'ios-restaurant-outline';
            } else if (route.name === 'Favorites') {
              iconName = focused ? 'ios-heart' : 'ios-heart-outline';
            }

            // You can return any component that you like here!
            return (
              <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={primaryColor} />
            );
          },
          tabBarActiveTintColor: primaryColor,
          tabBarInactiveTintColor: 'gray',
          headerShown: false,
        })}
      >
        <Tab.Screen name="All" component={CategoryNavigator} />

        <Tab.Screen name="Favorites" component={FavoriteNavigator} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```javascript
````

Comment: Because it doesn't look like you're using `Root` anywhere in `CategoryNavigator`

Comment: @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ I used it here: 
            <Item title="Menu" iconName="ios-menu" onPress={Root} />